# sIFR custom font method doesn't appear to work in linux?

Tags: fonts

In response to a question about custom fonts, I came across a link to a method using javascript/flash/css which is accessible. However, in my browser (Firefox 3/flash 10/Debian) it doesn't work. The website advertises that it works in Linux. Do any other Linux users have this issue? Here's the link:

http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/files/sifr/2.0/

Here's what I see:
[image](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4691/screenshot2ns6.png)

Comment: in what way does it not work? what do you see? screenshot?

Comment: http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4691/screenshot2ns6.png

Comment: That's better :-) No slagging off at SO or non-programming stuff at all here. Welcome, Me_here.

Comment: You did click the use sIFR "yes" on the left bar right?

Comment: @Andrew: yes, and refreshed several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually... the demo doesn't work with Flash 10, no matter for the OS. sIFR 3 fixes that. (or 2.0.7, which the demo  doesn't use).

More information at: http://novemberborn.net/sifr/2.0.7

Comment: Ah thanks. I guess that doesn't matter since the method degrades gracefully.